# fastest way to combine several text files without duplicate lines

Tags: python

I have several text files with SINGLE COLUMNS inside the directory . I have to combine all them into one text file by removing the duplicate lines. 
I am doing with the following code. However, my text files are extremely large. So what is the best and fastest way of doing it?

```
import os, glob
files = glob.glob('*.txt')

with open('combinedfile.txt','w') as fo:
    all_lines = []
    for f in files:
        with open(f,'r') as fi:
            all_lines.append(fi.read())
    all_lines = set(all_lines)

    for item in all_lines:
        fo.write(item + '\n')
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were saving the complete file content and not the individual lines so you would never find duplicates. I converted this to `readlines`. When writing you can join the text first and have one write which should give you some extra performance.

```
import os, glob
files = glob.glob('*.txt')

all_lines = []
for f in files:
    with open(f,'r') as fi:
        all_lines += fi.readlines()
all_lines = set(all_lines)

with open('combinedfile.txt','w') as fo:
    fo.write("\n".join(all_lines))
```

Comment: but why the code is producing space after every lines in the outfile?

Comment: a single space? Or what do you mean?

Comment: gap in every alternate line

Comment: is it possible that this stems from your input data? try changing the line to `all_lines = set([line.strip() for line in all_lines])`

Comment: Still some lines are empty.

Comment: `readlines()` retains the '\n' on the ends of lines. So change `"\n".join(all_lines)` to `"".join(all_lines)`. But first make sure that each source file ends with a '\n'.